# The order in which system Broadcast INTENTS are triggered from Power on to Shutdown of the phone? Androids boot process(intent order)

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to figure out what all INTENTS/ACTIONS are triggered and in what order during the life cycle of a phone from the time its powered on to its switched off.

NOTE: I am talking about system broadcast intents only that get triggered without any extra action, for eg dont consider incoming PHONE or SMS received broadcasts.

A solution could be something like :

...

...

ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

...

...

ACTION_REBOOT(SYS ONLY)

...

Can you guys help me to fill in the blanks?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

As correctly pointed out by zapl "Broadcasts are sent depending on events / hardware behavior / Android version etc" so I will try to make my question more clear by giving a scenario :

Lets consider a regular smartphone which has 
1. A working(active) network SIM
2. GPS
3. WIFI
4. SD Card
5. TouchScreen
6. Gyro
7..etc all other standard features of a smartphone today

Now, Forgetting about "events driven intents" i.e inserting SD, switching to Airplane Mode, Receving SMS, calling phone etc..which needs some kind of third party trigger to generate, can we come up with the most basic simplistic order of SYSTEM ACTION INTENTS once the power of the phone is switched on?

I am just trying to understand Androids boot process(order) as far as system INTENTS are concerned! May be there isnt one, may be its more dependent on hardware vendors than android itself.

Comment: Its always good to drop a small comment along with a negative vote so that people who are new to SO could help in making the system better and not just be left wondering..now what was wrong in asking that!!!

Answer (score 0):

Broadcasts are sent depending on events / hardware behavior / Android version etc. So there are probably no other intent you get for sure besides the BOOT_COMPLETED one. The order in which they appear is not fixed as well.

Therefore, relying on a specific order of them or assuming that something else also happened (like external sd card is mounted once BOOT_COMPLETED) will not work reliable. There are some that depend on other events to happen (like mediascanner will scan media after it is mounted) but I still wouldn't rely on that fact.

You could write a small app that registers for all broadcasts and just prints them to find out what happens on your device.

Comment: If this is true for internal system intents :  "The order in which they appear is not fixed as well." then I would consider my question answered. Thanks zapl!